# Design a builder pattern

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns, builder

How would I use the builder pattern for this or can you recommend any other pattern?

I have to build a object which contain multiple fields. But fields of the object will be filled on multiple steps of the API. The API is multithreaded and async. So the requirement is:

1. Fill some fields in one step and store it and again next step will
   pick the object and fill the field and in the last when all the
   fields are filled object will be constructed. So that Object will be
   immutable in the last.
2. As its a multithreaded environment so initially every request thread
   there should be one builder and one object. As the API is
       async if we cache the object and multiple threads needs to update
       the object field. But in the last it should be complete and immutable. How will i do that.
3. Is there any other design pattern I can think of.

Comment: Will there ever be only one object constructed at a time, or will there possibly be multiple objects constructed simultaneously?

Comment: Instead of `PersonBuilder set(String name) { this.name = name;  return this; }` you could use `Person with(String name) { Person p = new Person(this); p.name = name;  return p; }` - in other words always return a new object instead of mutating an existing one.

Comment: @Brett There will be one object for one request thread. If "X" no of requests are coming there will be "X" no of objects need to be constructed. So lets say a Class A contain  n fields. For a request R1 there will be m number of steps and all steps are asynchronous and among those steps some steps can be concurrent. Every step will fill x1(x1<n and every step will fill different fields) number of fields. If step thread S1 is modifying the object and step thread S2 also started modifying the same object but different fields.

Comment: @assylias new object creation at every field creation will not work.If you consider the scenario which i have described. As step S1 thread will get obj1 and step S2 thread will get obj2.

Comment: So, the single incoming request thread will possibly split into many step threads? Will the single incoming request thread wait until all the step threads have finished before finishing itself?

Comment: This seems a lot like homework (which is fine) but you should probably present some of your thinking here so we're not just doing it for you.

Comment: yes it will split into many step threads. And the single incoming request will wait until all the step threads have finished before finishing itself and in the last use it will use that constructed object for something.

Comment: All you need to do is ensure the fields of the builder are visible and block the waiting thread until he builder is filled as filling order does not matter.